# parent package does not execute child

Tags: ssis, bids

noob at SSIS here :)
I have a parent package that is supposed to execute a child package that will copy data from .csv. The child package runs fine on its own.
When I run the parent, i don't get an error or warning. It just kinda skips the execution of the child... I have other project/solutions with the same setup, and they run fine, all child packages are executed in them. But for some reason this time it's just ignoring it.
[data flow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OTwJj.png) and [execution results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vFWOe.png)

my batch configuration is set to execute this statement

> SELECT PackageName FROM Config.Batch WHERE BatchName='BATCH_NAME_' AND EnabledFlag='Enabled' ORDER BY ExecuteOrder

i do get this one warning which i can't seem to fix (been spending most of today trying to solve it, but can't find the error):

> Warning: 0x8001201A at X Parent: Configuration from a parent variable "ParentPackageKey" did not occur because there was no parent variable collection.

any help would be appricated

Comment: It looks like your Get Batch Configuration task is returning no results.   What have you done to confirm that it is returning results?

Comment: nothing really. i'm not sure how to do that to be honest

Comment: Well first of all, you could run that sql statement in SSMS and see if it returns results.   Double-check the task to verify it is executing against the correct server and database.

Comment: ah thank you!! there was a misspelling in the config.batch table of the dtsx file!